# DragShadowBuilder - Changing Shadow when over target?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, shadow

I know I can change the target when the shadow is over it, but I really want to change the shadow to indicate the action that will be performed to it when it is over the target.

I am able to modify the DragShadowBuilder when it is constructed by changing the output of onProvideShadowMetrics & onDrawShadow.

I have gone so far to add some public methods which can be accessed by the target and trying to update a class variable which holds the canvas & view, but it looks like it does not actually update when changes are made. This is my public method which gets called when the shadow is over the target.

```
    public void onTarget(String string) {
        mView.draw(mCanvas); 
        Paint redPaint = getFillTextPaint(0.00003f, 0xFFFF0000, 0.05225f);
        RectF r = new RectF();
        r.set(mCanvas.getWidth()-100.0f, 0,mCanvas.getWidth(), mCanvas.getHeight());
        mCanvas.drawRoundRect(r,8.0f,8.0f, redPaint);
        mView.invalidate();
    }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**DragShadowBuilder.onDrawShadow()** is invoked by **View.startDrag()** at the beginning of the drag and drop process.
Unfortunately native Drag and Drop, which was introduced with API level 11, does not support changing the bitmap after start.
Alternatively, you could roll your own Drag and Drop mechanism as shown, for example, [here](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html) and [here](http://doandroids.com/blogs/2010/6/25/android-drag-and-drop/), as it was done before API level 11.

Comment: I wonder if you put the Bitmap view in the LocalState Object if you could pull it out and modify it while being dragged. I may actually try that.

Comment: I dont't think that could work, as the Bitmap is drawn on a Surface which you cannot access. Have a look at the source code for [View](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/view/View.java?av=f#13313)

Comment: Is there a functioning example somewhere that shows a custom DragShadowBuilder drawing a different shape instead of the view the user touched ? I've searched for hours and nothing works...